# A question about spectral properties of a non-amenable group

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be a group generated by $a,b$ (for the sake of simplicity). Consider the element 
$$S=a+b+a^{-1}+b^{-1}\in{\mathbb C}[G],$$
which may also be interpreted as an operator in $l^2(G)$ (by left regular representation). Obviously $\|S\|\le 4$, and by the old result of Kesten
$\|S\|=4$ iff $G$ is amenable.

Now, suppose that $G$ is not amenable, that is,  $\|S\|<4$. Is there an eigenvector in $l^2(G)$  corresponding to the eigenvalue $\|S\|$?  (I do not know the answer even for a free group.)

Comment: What is $\parallel S\parallel$ in the case of the free group?

Comment: $S$ can be viewed as the adjacency operator of the Cayley graph.

Comment: Corbennick@ For a free group, $\|S\|=2\sqrt{3}$ (which is the minimal possible value).

Comment: You might want to look at the paper "Spectral Analysis for Adjacency Operators on Graphs" by Mantoiu et al.

Comment: The answer is always negative for infinite groups. This is a property of the random walk on the group. I remember that a result in the book of Woess implies that $\tau(S^n)/\|S\|^n$ converges zero. However, the weak limit is (or contains) the spectral projection at the point $\|S\|$.

Comment: Then I have two questions. (1)  What is the result? (2) I did not think about it first, but what about $l^p(G)$ for $p>2$?

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 7.8 in (W. Woess. Random walks on infinite graphs and groups. Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics Vol. 138, Cambridge University Press, 2000.) and/or the remarks after Excercise 14.32 in the notes of Gabor Pete, math.bme.hu/~gabor/PGG.pdf. I do not know about $l^p(G)$, but I would guess it is the same.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect that for $p>2$ it may be different, because the absence of eigenvectors does not follow from $\tau(S^n)/\|S\|^n\to 0$ (at least the way it does for $p=2$).

Comment: @AlexGavrilov Could you please let me know of a reference of "old result of ketsen ..." in your question?

Comment: H. Kesten.  Symmetric random walks on groups. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 92, 336-354 (1959).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linnell proved in his paper "Zero divisors and $\ell^2(G)$ C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 315 (1992), no. 1, 49-53." that all elements of the group ring of a right orderable groups, containing Abelian and  free groups, are nonzero divisors, i.e. if $0\neq\alpha\in\mathbb C[G]$, then for all $0\neq\beta\in\ell^2(G)$ we have $\alpha\beta\neq0\neq\beta\alpha$. So, in particular, the answer to your question in the case of right orderable groups is negative.